# Control flow pattern when checking for nonexistent variables

Tags: javascript

I saw the following pattern and tried adapting it to my own use:

```
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;
```

Simplifying:

```
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  "is ActiveX" : "not ActiveX";
document.write(request + "<br>");
// I get not ActiveX (Chrome)
```

Now when I try:

```
var notX = "x"; 
  var j = x ? "has x" : "no x";
  document.write(j + "<br>");
  // console error: x is not defined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mn8n/1/

Nothing gets outputted. What makes `window.ActiveXObject` different from `x` that the program continues to `document.write` but not in the case of `x`?

**-- More Importantly**

What's a robust pattern I can use to replace the above?

Comment: Yes, and `var j = window.x ? "has x" : "no x"` will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check for an undefined variable just by using it as-is, that's an error. The original code has no error because it's accessing it as a *property* of the `window` object; fetching undefined properties, instead of being an error, results in `undefined` in JavaScript.

To check for variables, you can use `typeof` instead.

```
var j = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? "has x" : "no x";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and variables pattern. Off-topic, I think your tic-tac-toe would improve with gridlines. I was stumped by the blank space. (Using Chrome). Impressive nonetheless :)

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo: <off-topic>I'll add those, thanks for playing :) [My tic-tac-toe is actually broken for me, though. I'm surprised you can get it, I thought the server was down...]</off-topic>

Answer (score 2):

There's a big difference between variables and properties (even though variables are *always* properties of some object; sometimes that object has no name and you have no way of directly accessing it, such as the *variable binding object* used when you call a function). When you do:

```
if (thingy.x) {
    // ...
}
```

...you're checking for a *property*. If the property doesn't exist, it's not an error, it's just that the value you get back is `undefined`.

In contrast, if you do:

```
if (x) {
    // ...
}
```

...you're checking for a *variable* called `x`. If `x` doesn't exist *at all*, it's an *error* (a `ReferenceError`, specifically), because the symbol `x` is completely undefined (as opposed to being a property with the *value* `undefined`).

This gets a bit murky when you're dealing with global variables, because global variables are properties of the global object, which is `window` in browsers. So if you have:

```
var x;
```

...at global scope, `if (x)` will work, as will `if (window.x)`, because `x` is a property of `window` (the global object). But there's a big difference, in that if `x` is *not* defined, `if (x)` will throw an error but `if (window.x)` will be falsey (because the expression `window.x` results in `undefined`).

Global scope is the only scope where this happens unless you use the `with` statement (which I recommend avoiding, for the reasons [Crockford discusses here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/)). (I don't always agree with Crockford, in fact I'd probably say it's only a 50% thing, but he has good points about `with`.)

You can *reliably* use `typeof` with any reference, even an undefined one, so:

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
}
```

...works even if `x` is completely undefined, and so that's usually the best way to check for whether something exists.

Comment: Thanks for adding all these details! I had a hard time whom to accept and chose the first answer.